# NIC seems slow, even on 100Mb/s full duplex

Tags: networking, connection, ethernet, nic

So I have a server running Centos 6 64bit with cPanel. It's set on eth0 running at 100MB/s full duplex. But, one particular server seems sluggish on its connectivity, despite server load being minimal on CPU and memory. Would like some tips on tracing the cause. I don't think the NIC card is faulty by any means. I tested via wget on 2 different U.S. mirrors for Centos 6 repo (4.4GB DVD), it was about 10M/s which should be a lot faster I'd think.

```
root@server [~]# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: off
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

Comment: 100MB/s is different than 100Mb/s. A 100Mb/s link speed gives a theoretical transfer rate of 12.5MB/s. Given the general overhead of a typical connection, a 10MB/s transfer rate on a 100Mb/s link is about right.

Answer (score 4):

As Rex mentioned, the difference there is in bits versus bytes. MB is megabytes, and Mb is megabits. Network speeds are *almost* always measured in bits. The 10 MB/s performance you're seeing is accurate, as your overall speed is 12.5 MB/s. Factor in dropped packets, error corrections, other services' network usage, etc. and your speed is on par.

A gigbit (1 Gb/s) full duplex link will give you 125 MB/s tops.